# What can non-elevated rm -rf /* actually remove on macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, command-line, permission, ventura

Long story short I am an idiot and ran `rm -rf /*` on my M2 MacBook Pro running macOS Ventura 13.3.1 while trying to clear out a directory.

I was able to cancel it a few seconds after realizing what I had done, but not before deleting some files. I don't have any OS backups, but that good news is that all my important files are backed up on GitHub or Google Drive. All that I can tell happened is some applications (my browser, Steam, etc.) were fully deleted or no longer work properly.

This is of course fine, I can just reinstall those, but I fear that some system files were deleted without my knowledge. Tons of files in `/Library` and some in `/Applications` were not deleted due to "Permission Denied", but I can't be sure that there aren't some that were deleted.

My questions are:

1. Should I do a clean install to be safe.
2. If I were to just update to Sonoma, would any missing system files be reinstalled?

I will definitely be making backups in the future!

Comment: You wouldn't need to do a clean install, just install the version you were running over the top.

Comment: I would advise the importance of having a local backup, so that you can restore things like Preferences, Application Support files, and anything else that doesn't count as "important files". It's also much faster and easier to restore a whole disk locally when you don't know what's missing.

Comment: It could be worth it to check whether you have any [APFS snapshots](https://support.apple.com/en-us/guide/disk-utility/dskuf82354dc/mac). Sometimes you might, even if no backups are enabled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without `sudo` you are only able to delete the files in your user home folder and configuration files (think /private/var and /private/etc).

If you want to be super cautious, do [a safe boot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) to clean and signal a full rebuild of the /private cached files.

As to things you may have deleted before stopping the remove, you can see what was on the chopping block with this command:

```
ls -R /* | more
```

It starts with /Applications – so you'll need to reinstall any that were missing, but you won't lose any Application data as it's not stored in the App bundle.

Next up is /Library – so some Application Support files might be missing (but if you didn't lose all the third party apps, it's unlikely it went on to library or even deep into Applications as `rm -ri /*` goes depth first whereas `ls` goes breadth first.

```
# be very careful to only say yes to list files
# say no to any file deletion request
# but you can see exactly what rm would delete next on your
# Mac so you know what wasn't completely deleted
rm -ri /*
```

The interactive remove above is relatively safe as it asks before each removal. But go VERY SLOWLY – it first asks if you want to examine each directory but then when there are no more directories, it asks if you want to remove files one by one... So initially y is a safe answer and then it isn't (until you have a backup and know you can restore from it).

You do not need to do anything with macOS reinstall – there's nothing you can remove, even with `sudo` and reinstalling won't hurt or help.

TLDR; Look over Applications you installed and maybe /Library if every single app you installed is gone.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: And even with `sudo` permission, SIP should prevent deletion in critical system folders.

Comment: SIP no longer is involved with permissions once the system is sealed at Install time by macOS as a read only APFS snapshot - it's about code execution paths @Barmar on Ventura. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection

Comment: @bmike Maybe I have my terminology wrong, but I thought MacOS has protections that prevent any unauthorized code from modifying critical system directories. Perhaps it's part of the sandboxing.

Comment: The system volume is sealed - one bit flips and the Mac will not boot, @Barmar  https://eclecticlight.co/2020/11/30/is-big-surs-system-volume-sealed/

Comment: Thanks. I'm way out of date in how MacOS system security has evolved.

Comment: I bet this comment chain will help others. Thanks for the comment and question @Barmar SIP is much more complicated on Apple Silicon - https://support.apple.com/guide/security/contents-a-localpolicy-file-mac-apple-silicon-secc745a0845/web ( see sip0, sip1, sip2, sip3 and all the verifications for booting)